# js change event not called after program change the value

Tags: javascript, aurelia

i use #Aurelia and ES6 in my project and in a keydown event when keykode is 38 (arrowup) i change inner input value and add number to it:

```
this.element.value = this.element.value +100;
```

and it work but after Enter key or unfocus change event not trigger in aurelia change.bind is ther any way to change event vaiable or other places i can say value is changed to js and after unfocus or press enter key change Event fire?

Comment: You can use the `@observable` decorator however it'll need to be on a property within the scope of `this`. A little more context with your code will help us answer.

Comment: I agree with @thebluefox. Also, not all browsers recognise "enter key" as a change event, so this approach might not work perfectly.